# custom notification not showing on lock screen oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, lockscreen

I am building  Notification with remote views. I have given NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC. but Notification is not showing on lock screen in Oreo.

My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 27

```
 remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.player_noti_layout);
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                getString(R.string.player_channel),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setDescription("Notification, Play/pause & Next/Prev");
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notificationmanager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default");
    Notification foregroundNote;
    // Set Icon
    foregroundNote = builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio)
            .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setContentTitle("app name").setContentText("").setWhen(0).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) 
            .build();
```

Help appreciated!!! Thanks

Comment: try changing `IMPORTANCE_LOW` to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`

Comment: @user7940066 u found any solution?

Comment: @UrMi i changed NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW to NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT and  NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC to Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Notification.Builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found working for me is in your notificationchannel you change the LockscreenVisibility to this

```cs
channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
```

And in your NotificationCompat.Builder

```cs
.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilityPublic)
```

You do seem to be using a slightly different Syntax as for me I had to capitalise .SetVisibility 

I hope this still helps.

PS: Keep in mind that your phone might not allow lockscreen notifications. This also happened to me where the code worked but my phone still didn't show the notifications. ;)